# style="display: none" not working

Tags: html, css, struts2

I created actions to pre-populate lists that I can reuse for different jsp pages.  I need to be able to show/hide these lists using javascript.  I used the following code but it is not working.

I'm using struts2 and spring

javascript

```
document.getElementById("hihDiv").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("hihDiv").style.display = '';
```

jsp

```
<tr id="hihDiv" style="display: none">
    <td class="leftAligned"><s:action name="HIHRef" executeResult="true" /></td>
</tr>
```

action jsp

```
<s:select id="reviewContractor" size="5" name="reviewContractor" size="1"  list="reviewContractors"
                                label="Review Contractor" onchange="showReviewContractor(this.value)"/>

<s:select size="5" size="1" id="hih" list="hihs"  name="hih" label="HIH" />
```

The lists are pre-populating fine but when I change the selection for the reviewContractor select it should show/hide the hihDiv row and it is not working.  I'm not sure if it is not working because of the `<s:action>` tag.  When I used a select with the options in the jsp page the javascript worked but I was unable to pre-populate the lists from the database.  Now with the `s:action` tag I can pre-populate the lists but the show/hide is not working.

Any suggestions please??

Here is my javascript.  There are several selects that need to show/hide but I want to get one working first.

```
function showReviewContractor(val){ 

    var value = parseInt(val);  
    alert(value);

    switch(value){

    case 0:
        document.getElementById("hihDiv").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("claimDiv").style.display = '';
        document.getElementById("racDiv").style.display = '';
        document.getElementById("macDiv").style.display = '';
        document.getElementById("certDiv").style.display = '';
        document.getElementById("permDiv").style.display = '';
        alert("all");
        break;
    case 1: //rac

        document.getElementById("claimDiv").style.display = '';
        document.getElementById("racDiv").style.display = '';
        document.getElementById("hihDiv").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("macDiv").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("certDiv").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("permDiv").style.display = 'none';
        alert("rac");

        break;
    case 2: //mac

        document.getElementById("claimDiv").style.display = '';
        document.getElementById("macDiv").style.display = '';
        document.getElementById("hihDiv").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("racDiv").style.display = 'none';       
        document.getElementById("certDiv").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("permDiv").style.display = 'none';
        alert("mac");
        break;
    case 3: //cert

        document.getElementById("claimDiv").style.display = '';
        document.getElementById("certDiv").style.display = '';
        document.getElementById("hihDiv").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("racDiv").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("macDiv").style.display = 'none';       
        document.getElementById("permDiv").style.display = 'none';

        break;
    case 4: //perm

        document.getElementById("claimDiv").style.display = '';
        document.getElementById("permDiv").style.display = '';
        document.getElementById("hihDiv").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("racDiv").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("macDiv").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("certDiv").style.display = 'none';

        break;
    /*case 5:
        document.getElementById("hihDiv").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("claimDiv").style.display = '';
        document.getElementById("racDiv").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("macDiv").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("certDiv").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("permDiv").style.display = 'none';

        break;
    case 6:
        document.getElementById("hihDiv").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("claimDiv").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("racDiv").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("macDiv").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("certDiv").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("permDiv").style.display = 'none';
        break;
    case 7:
        document.getElementById("hihDiv").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("claimDiv").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("racDiv").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("macDiv").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("certDiv").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("permDiv").style.display = 'none';

        break;
        */
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: in your jsp you might be missing a semi-colon `style="display: none;"`

Comment: Could you post your full JavaScript? I guess the JavaScript you’ve posted is the contents of your `showReviewContractor` function, but it’s not clear what’s going on from what you’ve posted so far.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you've explicitly set the theme to "simple", the `<s:select>` tag will be rendering its own table rows/cells, creating invalid HTML. (I'd have to check if the S2 form tags must be explicitly nested in a form tag as in S1, I *think* it'd work as you have it delta not creating bogus HTML).

```
<s:select (all your stuff, but add) theme="simple" />
```

I'd really recommend not doing it like this, though--rather create the select list in the action and expose it directly to the JSP.

Comment: I just have the form using the theme=simple.  Not the actually s:select

Comment: @user1046203 Did you try it? Also, check the DOM after action execution. Might want to consider jQuery/etc, too, or at least just keep arrays of IDs instead of repeating all that cruft.

Comment: After I added the theme="simple" it worked!!  Thank you!!!  I was pulling my hair out!

Comment: @user1046203 I suspect since the form isn't in the select's immediate context the hierarchical lookup isn't working. I'd still not do it like this though.

Comment: I'm up for any suggestions.  Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: @user1046203 Expose the list in the action, and put the selects into the same JSP.

Answer (score 0):

try putting the form style as simple in jsp struts2 form and try to look in how do you call the function because maybe you're doing something wrong